# Load content before call a function

Tags: javascript, loading, html5-audio

I just started to practice code in asynchronous programming. And I'm little bit confused, why I could not get the application working correctly.

I'm trying to load json data in a var jsonItems.
Load the sound, and play.

```
function getJItems(jsonItems, callback){

$.getJSON( "data.json", function( data ) {
    jsonItems.push(data);

});

    callback(jsonItems);    
}

var sI = [];

function loadSoundJson(jsonItems){

    for (it =0 ; it < jsonItems[0].length ; it++){
        sI[it] = new buzz.sound( "data/"+jsonItems[0][it].filesound, { formats: [ "ogg", "mp3"] });
    }

};
```

This is how I try to call.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {


    getJItems(jsonItems,loadSoundJson);

});
```

The error that I get is: jsonItems[0] is undefined

If I write, works fine.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {


    getJItems(jsonItems);
        window.alert("forced pause");
        loadSoundJson(jsonItems);

});
```

So, I just want to be sure, that whole content (images, sound, data) will be loaded and ready before the application starts.

Maybe what I want is, know how to implement the correct way to making a good loading page.
thanks in advance.

Comment: It's async, you're trying to use the data before it's available, and this is a duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getJItems(jsonItems, callback){

   $.getJSON( "data.json", function( data ) {
      jsonItems.push(data);
      callback(jsonItems); 
   });


}
```

You were not calling the callback at the right moment. getJSON is async hence when the data are available they will get pushed into jsonItems. At first `callback(jsonItems);` was being executed before any data was available.

What you were doing at the first place was execute `getJItems()` do an ajax call (without waiting for reply) call the callback